# Dirty card table and the 4 zones

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I saw the presentation [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gee7QfoY8ys) where he talks about G1 garbage collector.

He explains from around 14 minutes into the video about dirty card tables (not card tables) which are some queue that holds the changes of references etc. These changes do not get directly reflected into to the remembered sets (RSet), but only when dirty card table gets filled up and moves from e.g. the white to red zone.

I got two questions:

1 - Is it correctly understood then that for a young collection, the algorithm might need to use the dirty card table rather than the RSet - since ReSt might not have got the updates yet. Also, does that not undermine the whole objective to have RSet, so we avoid having to go through several zones ?

2 - Where can I find more material about this - and is it still relevant. I am finding very little info on this, and I was getting suspecious whether the dirty card tables and zones are still used in the later Java versions

Comment: Look at ~18:00 Young GC Phases, “Second Phase: Update RS”